# How to use a bash script to write to a mysql table

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm using a bash script to pull data from online sources. Right now I just have it writing to a text file, but it would be better if the script could automatically put this data into mysql tables. How can this be done? Examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you download a `.csv` file. which has header and have a database `test` in mysql.

Download the file first.

```
     wget http://domain.com/data.csv -O data.csv
```

Dump the data to mysql table `tbl`

```
     cat <<FINISH | mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD test
         LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE `tbl`
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
         IGNORE 1 LINES;
     FINISH
```

Here `USERNAME` must have `FILE` privilege.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

params="dbname -uuser -ppassswd"

echo "SELECT * FROM table;" | mysql $params
# or 
mysql $params <<DELIMITER
SELECT * FROM table;
DELIMITER
```